# Normal Temperature of Dell Inspiron N4050

Tags: temperature

My laptop is Dell Inspiron N4050. Now I am using Jupiter. While using Ubuntu it shows the CPU temperature is between 45°C - 65°C. Is it okay for my laptop? Mine CPU temperature is between 48°C-55°C most of the time. As I mentioned 45°C is the minimum and 65°C is the Maximum. Is it okay for my Laptop? What do you say, should I stop worrying?

Comment: 45 to 55 is ok ... please have a look at http://askubuntu.com/questions/285434/jupiter-or-similar-power-saving-app-for-13-04/285681#285681

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Dell your laptop can have 3 different processors.  These processors are listed below with their max temperatures.

According to Intel:

If you have Intel Pentium Processor B950 (2M Cache, 2.10 GHz) the maximum temperature allowed at the processor die is 85°C

If you have Intel Core i5-2430M Processor (3M Cache, up to 3.00 GHz) the maximum temperature allowed at the processor die is 100°C

If you have Intel Core i3-2330M Processor (3M Cache, 2.20 GHz) the maximum temperature allowed at the processor die is 85°C - 100°C

So by that since your is between 45°C - 65°C you should be OK.

As per your comment, that you have Intel Core i3-2350M CPU @ 2.30GHz, just see images below:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Mine Processor is Intel® Core™ i3-2350M CPU @ 2.30GHz × 4. As you are saying is the temperature is okey which I mentioned ?

Comment: That is correct.  I have added 2 images in my answer that show the max temp.