# MATE Sensors Applet 1.12.1

Tags: asus, mate, temperature

G'day,

Just a simple question regarding which sensor (MATE sensor Applet 1.12.1) is which, I can't seem to find anything on it even on ASUS sites. (I'm running MATE 16.04 on an X550LA ASUS laptop with 12GB RAM)

What I have is Fan sped, plus 6 temperatures, two of which have sensor high values of 100 degrees C, I assume these are the two cores, but the others have high values of 60 degrees C and I just don't know enough about computers to even hazard a guess as to what they are, if they're high, normal etc.

I'd really appreciate someone's help, also if this has been addressed elsewhere I apologize, but I couldn't find anything.

Hal.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Normal Temperature of Dell Inspiron N4050](https://askubuntu.com/questions/295179/normal-temperature-of-dell-inspiron-n4050)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could determine sensors type by

1. right-clicking on *MATE Sensors Applet* on mate-panel
2. selecting *Preferences*,
3. then go to *Sensors* tab,
4. expand *libsensors* (on my system I have only this line) tree.

60 degrees C is normal, I think. I write this answer with such value.
100 degrees C is very high for CPU, it is called CPU Junction.
You can consult [Intel page](https://ark.intel.com/products/81015/Intel-Core-i7-4510U-Processor-4M-Cache-up-to-3_10-GHz) for correct value.

> T_JUNCTION
>   Junction Temperature is the maximum temperature allowed at the processor die.

Also you can determine critical values from `sensors` command in terminal.

Comment: Thank you NObert I appreciate your answer. My problem when I do what you suggest I see three "temp1"and  I have no idea what they refer to. I also see "core1" "core2". I can work these out by their location on the panel. Thank you gain, I shall keep looking and post any relevant information.